# Structure having an array of pointers in c

Tags: c++, struct

I am implementing multibit trie in C. I am getting segmentation fault error. When I run the program. I don't know what is going wrong?

The node of Multi bit trie is like that:

```
struct MtNode{
        /* nodes is an array 8 elements. Each element is a pointer to its child node.*/
        MtNode* nodes[8];  // 2^stride = 2^3 = 8
        int   nexthop;
    };
```

Each node is initialized as following:

```
typedef MtNode node;
node *init_mtnode(){
    node *ret = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));   
    int size = (int)pow(2,STRIDE);
    for (int i=0; i<size ; ++i)
    {
           ret->nodes[i] = NULL;
    }    
    ret->nexthop = -1;
    return ret;
}
```

Is anything wrong in init_mtnode method?

Comment: `MtNode* nodes[8];` --> `struct MtNode* nodes[8];`

Comment: Are you sure it's c? In [tag:c] the declarations you have would be wrong, they are valid in [tag:c++] though. Also, don't cast `pow` to int like that, and you don't need to cast `malloc()` either, again *unless it's [tag:c++]*.

Comment: If i dont cast malloc, I get compilation error. @iharob. and actually i use c++ compiler cause i need some library of c++ such maps.. but the work is just a procedual programming...that's why i put c tag

Comment: @BLUEPIXY...i tried with struct MtNode* nodes[8];....same error..segfault

Comment: No, you should put the tag corresponding to the programming language you use, for example you should use `new` instead of `malloc()` and also, `maps` is not a library they are part of `stl` from standard c++.

Comment: @iharob i think tag is not a matter of concern right now

Comment: It is, the help you get depends on that. And c solutions might be a bad choice in c++ and c++ solutions will not generally work in c. Also, there are some situations where a c solution will not work in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possible reasons:

1. You don't check `malloc()` for `NULL`, unlike `new` which would throw an exception, `malloc()` will return `NULL` if an error happens.
2. You calculate the value of `size` and then loop `size` times, but your array can only hold `8` pointers.

Try this

```
typedef MtNode node;
node *init_mtnode()
{
    node *ret;
    int size;
    ret = static_cast<node *>(malloc(sizeof(node)));
    if (ret == NULL) /* check for NULL */
        return NULL;
    size = 2 << STRIDE;
    if (size >= 8)
        size = 7; /* maximum possible value */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
        ret->nodes[i] = NULL;
    ret->nexthop = -1;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Then the error is not in this code. What is the value of `STRIDE`?

Comment: its 3..#define STRIDE 3

Comment: See how I fixed your code, it will not take away the segmentation fault, but this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Ok...i see..but for now, i got error called "nullptr is not declared in scope" ..I am using g++ in linux now to compile my code

Comment: it compiles...but the segfault is ther!

Comment: Please post the rest if the code, build the smallest possible program that will reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @iharob...thanks for the help...there is nothing wrong in this piece of code!!...i will check rest!

Comment: ...Can you please help me further? ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936609/trie-implementation-in-c-c