# Trie implementation in c

Tags: c, trie

I am implementing multibit trie in C. When I run the code, I get run-time error: bus error (core dumped). I am getting this error when I am adding different nodes through calling insert_rule method.

I wrote comments in code to understand.

This code is written as multibit.h header file and this methods are being called from another .c file. Codes in caller.c file are perfectly right. I also checked init_mtnode method by sample test code. Init_mtnode method is also perfectly fine.

```
    #define STRIDE 3

    /* each node in trie is struct of c code*/
    struct MtNode{
        /* nodes is an array 8 elements. Each element is a pointer to its child node.*/
        struct MtNode* nodes[8];  // 2^stride = 2^3 = 8
        int   nexthop;
    };

    typedef struct MtNode node;

    struct MtNode* helper(MtNode *curr_node, uint32_t prefix_r, int prelen, int portnum, int b);
    uint32_t* paddingFunction(uint32_t prefix_r, int prelen, int padded_prelen);

    /* Initialize multibit trie node */
    node* init_mtnode(){
        node *ret;
        int size;
        ret = static_cast<node *>(malloc(sizeof(node)));
        if (ret == NULL) /* check for NULL */
            return NULL;
        size = 2 << STRIDE;
        if (size >= 8)
            size = 7; /* maximum possible value */
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
               ret->nodes[i] = NULL;
        ret->nexthop = -1;
        return ret;
    }

    /* Clean up binary trie */
    void free_mt(struct MtNode *root){
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)pow(2,STRIDE); i++){
        free_mt(root->nodes[i]);
        }    
        free(root);
    }

    /* Insert a rule */
    /* prefix is a 32 bit integer. But its "prelen (MSB - prefix length bits)" bits are counted */
    /* prelen - prefix length = Mask "
    /* portnum - port number to be saved as next hop*/
    void insert_rule(struct MtNode* root, uint32_t prefix, int prelen, int portnum){

        static int n_rules = 0;    
        n_rules ++;
        printf("rules: %d\n", n_rules);

        if( prelen == 0){
            root->nexthop = portnum;
            return;
        }
        if(prelen % STRIDE == 0){
            root = helper(root, prefix, prelen, portnum, 0);
        }else{
            int expansion = STRIDE - (prelen%STRIDE); 
            int padded_prelen = prelen + expansion;
            uint32_t *prefixes;
            prefixes = paddingFunction(prefix, prelen, padded_prelen);
            for(int i = 0; i < (int)pow(2,expansion); i++){
                root = helper(root, *(prefixes + i) , padded_prelen, portnum, 0);
            }
            free(prefixes);
        }       
    }

struct MtNode* helper(struct MtNode* curr_node, uint32_t prefix, int prelen, int portnum, int b){
    //printf("%u\n", prefix_r);
    uint32_t  temp_prefix = prefix; 
    if(b==prelen){
       curr_node->nexthop = portnum;    
       return curr_node;        
    }

    /* get first 3 bits of prefix as index*/
    temp_prefix = (prefix << b);
    temp_prefix = temp_prefix & 0xE0000000;
    temp_prefix = temp_prefix >> 29;
    int index = (int) temp_prefix;


    if(curr_node->nodes[index] == NULL){
        curr_node->nodes[index] = init_mtnode();
    }

    curr_node->nodes[index] = helper(curr_node->nodes[index], prefix, prelen, portnum, b+STRIDE);
    return curr_node;   
}

/* this method pads '0's and '1's if prefix is not divisible by STRIDE
   if prefix = 1111* , it returns array [111100 , 111101 , 1111111]*/

uint32_t *paddingFunction(uint32_t prefix_r, int prelen, int padded_prelen){
    int expansion = padded_prelen - prelen;
    int size = (int) pow(2,expansion);
    uint32_t *arr = (uint32_t *)malloc(size*sizeof(uint32_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        uint32_t temp = i;
        temp = temp << (31-prelen);
        arr[i] = prefix_r | temp; 
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Try with a debugger and check where exactly the problem is, and please choose a language, c and c++ are very different languages.

Comment: thanks @iharob!!...i will figure out...

Answer (score 1):

The line where you call the `helper()` function

```
root = helper(root, *(prefixes + i) , prelen, portnum, 0);
```

you should pass `padded_prelen` in place of `prelen` because you increment b by the `STRIDE` length each time. And if you compare it with he `prelen`, it will never be equal to that unless

```
prelen % STRIDE == 0
```

Comment: This `*(prefixes + i)` is absolutely unnecessary, just use `prefixes[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for that...I also found it few mins ago...now i am working on segfault error...thanks @shorya gupta